# MakeHuman model not retargetting correctly to mocap bvh file

Tags: animation, makehuman, bvh

I am involved in a research project where I collected mocap BVH files from Kinect (converted CSV to BVH files) for yoga poses and I am making synthetic humans animation for yoga poses. I am using Blender for rendering animations.

I am facing issues with retargetting the BVH fie to my Make human model and it is not giving a very nice animation.

In this image the skeleton is an imported BVH file and another is a retargetted Makehuman character for the same BVH file:

[image]

You can see the strange behaviour among the rig of the MH model and the mesh and other objects such as clothes.

I am not sure what the problem is, I am unable to figure it out. Can you guys help me out with some important steps while creating animations with Makehuman, Makewalk and BVH files? I am using .mhx2 files for the character model.

Comment: I also experience that. The motion is not smooth

Comment: did you solve the problem when you faced the same issue? @IsraelBamidele

Comment: No. What I discover is that the *Mocap BVH* is having too much keyframes. Trying to simplify the *Keyframes* makes it even worse. So I do prefer *Keyframing* it myself rather than using *Mocap BVH*

Comment: Bunny would you be able to share your code for converting csv to bvh?  I am using OpenFace https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace   to caputre facial 3d landmarks data and need to convert it to bvh.  Thanks.

Comment: hi @dan, since i was working on the project under a university professor, he has not allowed me to reveal the code yet, i can provide you the github repo https://github.com/meshonline/kinect-openni-bvh-saver which helped us in the project. code for Conversion of CSV to BVH is used from the same repo with some edits.

Comment: @Bunny Thanks for the info!